# Li items get shown under, instead of next to, each other when width is not fixed

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm currently really busy working on a simple jQuery slideshow, but I've got the following problem, when I make my slides a fixed width like:

```
#slider ul {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
}

#slider ul li {
float:left;
height: 100%;
width:200px;
}
```

It all works fine; but when I want to make my slider full-screen. So Instead of width 200

```
width:100%;
```

All the li's get displayed beneath each other instead of next to each other. I hope I provided enough information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the width is `100%` the `li` element occupies the full width of its parent container, meaning there's no room for another `li` element to occupy the same line; the `width` explicitly *forces* the next sibling to the next line.

To work around this, one option, given the following mark-up:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/nightlife/Some%20sample%20text" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/sports/Some%20sample%20text" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is to use:

```
ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

li,
img {
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3bUVq/).

Which forces the `ul` to keep elements in a single 'line', assigns a `100%` width to the `li` and `img` elements, and displays the `li` elements as in-line.

Comment: and what would be the best way to work around this? I was thinking of making it absolute and give each slide manually a margin left. But I assume there would be a more clean way to do this..?